# jQuery Date Range Picker add recurrence feature

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, daterangepicker

I want to do varies type of recurrence from **Date Range Picker** using jQuery. Those are below.

```
Recurrent day/week/month/year
Recurrent date untill/for/forever 
Period day/week/month/year numbers ...
```

Almost like the calender in thundurbird or outlook or ....

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ohloh.net/p/jquery-recurrenceinput-js

Haven't used it yet, so please let me know if it works ok.